# Locate source of error in system.log (src/__default.php)

Tags: system.log

Do you know how to fix error in System.log?

```
2015-04-23T22:47:45+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT  in /public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 14331
```

We have an inventory management module that won't connect to our Magento store via API. Hoping this error in sytem.log will help us resolve the issue.

Your ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Please disable compiler and check again

Answer (score 1):

You have compiler enabled which makes this difficult to debug. If you disable the compiler it will allow you to determine which file the error is happening in.

Somewhere in your code is this $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
HTTP_USER_AGENT is optional and not always present.

A temporary workaround is in the start of index.php you could put

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = '';
```

However I would highly recommend finding where this is in the code and adding code to handle the HTTP_USER_AGENT not being set.